# ADsOpenObject bind unsuccessful

Tags: c++, binding, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to **connect to an AD server** from a computer that is outside the domain **using ADSI** however the **bind is unsuccessful**. Using Visual c++ 2010 express.

Here is the code snippet:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <wchar.h>
    #include <objbase.h>
    #include <activeds.h>
    #include <AdsHlp.h>

    using namespace std;

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
    {
        IADs *pObject;
        HRESULT hr;

        hr = ADsOpenObject(L"LDAP://aswathy-server3/cn=users,dc=aswathy,dc=local",
            L"administrator", 
            L"password",
            ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, 
            IID_IADs,
            (void**)&pObject);

        if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            cout<<"Success";
            pObject->Release();
        }
        else
            cout<<"Unsuccessful";
    getch();
            return 0;
    }
```

I have included adsiid,lib and activeds.lib under project properties -> linker -> input -> additional dependencies.

Does anyone know why bind is not successful?

Comment: surly there is some security issue. And once more is check out your password and user name, Is it correct.

Comment: What sort of security issue? I have checked the credentials already.

Comment: What is the error code?

Comment: ERROR_NO_SUCH_DOMAIN probably

Answer (score 0):

hr = ADsOpenObject(L"WinNT://aswathy.local/users",
            L"administrator", 
            L"password",
            ADS_SECURE_AUTHENTICATION, 
            IID_IADs,
            (void**)&pObject);

Comment: Can you explain why the OP should use WinNT vs LDAP?